# JaxWS, JaxRS Apache CXF + Springboot SOAP and RESFTful services in same project

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, cxf, jax-ws, java-ee-8

I am migrating an app from Spring to Springboot. The application has a bunch of SOAP and REST services written with Jaxws and Jaxrs.
I migrated the SOAP services using CXF and want to use CXF for RESTful as well. But, as soon as I register the Rest Server my application starts to break.

These are the two dependencies I am using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**My Soap Service:**

```
package com.example.soap;

import com.example.domain.Student;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@Service
@WebService(serviceName = "/MySuperSoapAPI", targetNamespace = "http://mysuperapp.com")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE,use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL)
public class MySuperSoapService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetStudent")
    @WebResult(name = "Student")
    public Student getStudent(@XmlElement(required = true) @WebParam(name = "Student") Student student){
        return student;
    }
}
```

**My Restful service**

```
package com.example.rest;

import com.example.domain.Student;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Service
@Path("/student")
public class MyRestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Student getStudent() {
        return new Student("Saifur", "Rahman", "061240");
    }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
package com.example.config;

import com.example.rest.MyRestService;
import com.example.soap.MySuperSoapService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider;
import org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private SpringBus bus;

    @Autowired
    private MySuperSoapService mySuperSoapService;

    @Autowired
    private MyRestService myRestService;

    @Bean
    public Endpoint getStudentEndPoint(){
        EndpointImpl endpoint=new EndpointImpl(bus,mySuperSoapService);
        endpoint.publish("/student");
        return endpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public Server rsServer() {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        endpoint.setBus(bus);
        endpoint.setAddress("/");
        endpoint.setServiceBeans(Arrays.asList(myRestService));
        endpoint.setProvider(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());
        return endpoint.create();
    }

}
```

**Properties**

```
cxf.path=/service
#cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true
#cxf.jaxrs.classes-scan-packages=com.example.rest
```

My Questions are:

1. Can I use Apache CXF for both RS and WS in the same project? Then, how?
2. I can also use the spring boot for RESTful if that is easier. But, cannot seem to configure to get that working either.

Any suggestion/help is appreciated.

The complete project is released in [Github](https://github.com/safrrhmn/JavaEE-ApacheCXFSoapAndRestService/tree/master)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use them together. But you can't have same path for them.
Just update one of next paths "/student". Keep them different.

```
@Bean
public Endpoint getStudentEndPoint(){
    EndpointImpl endpoint=new EndpointImpl(bus,mySuperSoapService);
    endpoint.publish("/student");
    return endpoint;
}

@Service
@Path("/student")
public class MyRestService {
   ...
```